# Open two instances of the same app on Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I am looking for a trick in which to open the same app twice. Let me explain.

For example, I have an app called SQLite Database Browser but it can only handle one SQL DB at a time. I would like to start another SQLite DB Browser so I can open another SQL DB file. How do I do that?

Comment: I do this with Firefox occasionally by creating multiple browser profiles. OS X then sees each instance of Firefox with a unique profile as a separate application.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you use [open](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) from the command line you can pass a parameter to start a new instance:

```
open -n /Applications/TextEdit.app
```

Or, alternatively:

```
open -n -a TextEdit
```

Another way is to find the Unix executable in the app bundle and run it:

```
/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit &
```

Comment: One could use `Automator.app` to create a small application that uses this command line to launch a second instance. That would eliminate the need to always type that into a Terminal.

Comment: @Mark. Excellent. The open -n works great. I haven't tried the Unix executable but I'll keep that in mind. @ slhck. scripting will do the trick. If I need to use the command over and over again, I'll definitely make one. Thanks everybody!!!

Comment: @slhck When using Automator, select "Services" and "Shell Script". Use clover-S to save, and go to keyboard shortcuts, "Services" to find this script and assign it to a shortcut. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24063/create-global-shortcut-to-run-command-line-applications/40887#40887

Comment: just alias it, eg. alias textedit='open -n /Applications/TextEdit.app'

Comment: In both: Linux and Windows, I just middle-click the app on the taskbar, or click on it from the app list (about 1-2s depending on the screen resolution and mouse distance to the icon). Having 2 application profiles pointing to the same app is IMO not a good solution: what if I need 3 or 4 instances? Will it take 2 spaces on my taskbar if I use none? Will I have to choose which of the two icons I already have open and which I have to click? Apple have a looooot to learn from KDE taskbar, or even Windows taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

I know with CarbonCopyCloner I can make another copy of the application itself and I can open two instances of CCC at the same time. Have you tried something like that?

Comment: So, use CCC to create another copy of the SQLite application?

Comment: No @mdgarci was just giving CCC as an example - just copy your app with finder -- but for better way see my answer

Comment: @Mark Classy example of advertising your answer - but good job on yours.